# How to see whether installed CUDA is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: cuda

Is there any command or any file in the CUDA directory which can answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

`file /path/to/cuda/bin/executable`

I.e.,

`file /home/user/cuda/bin/cudademo`

Comment: Thanks for reply.cuda is in usr/local/cuda, so you mean cudademo is in usr/local/cuda/bin ? Because, I don't see cudademo there.

Comment: I dont know where you have installed it, and cant remember what the executables are called.  I did a quick search on the location of the bins, and thats what it gave me.  I wish I could put a paragraph mark </>  anyway, /usr/local/cuda.  Look for an executable it may be in the bin dir, it may be in the cuda directory, and then just run file on it.  Will tell you if its 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: I didn't find any executable in /usr/local/cuda, but I ran this: ......@ubuntu:/usr/local/cuda/bin$ file nvcc
nvcc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped.    Does this mean its 64 bit ? Any other way to confirm ?

Comment: That's as far as I know.  It is a 64bin.  Looks to be the nvidia control panel.  and /usually/ all the binaries are one arch.

Comment: There are lines in some files which have x86_64 written. I guess mine have to be 64 bit. I had compatibility issues and have doubt, so I was looking for a solid proof. Thanks for help though !